# Reading and Setting Variables using the Saved Session Variables

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, session, sql-server-2008-r2, session-variables

I added the username, role, and userID to a session, and the session is save in SQL Server. If the user were to close and reopen the browser while the session is not yet expired, how do I obtain the previous values that were added to the session?
For example, the following values were added to the session.

```
 SessionWrapper.currentRequest.UserName = model.UserName;
        SessionWrapper.currentRequest.Role = aRole;
        SessionWrapper.currentRequest.UserId = userId;
```

The user closes the browser and reopens it; the session is not expired. How do I restore the session so that these variables remains intact?

**`//This is the object that is wrapped in the session`**

```
public class CurrentRequest
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string Role { get; set; }
    }
```

**`//The session Wrapper`**

```
 public class SessionWrapper
            {
                public static CurrentRequest currentRequest
                {
                    get
                    {
                        if (HttpContext.Current.Session["request"] != null)
                        {
                            return (CurrentRequest)HttpContext.Current.Session["request"];
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return null;
                        }
                    }
                    set
                    {
                        HttpContext.Current.Session["request"] = value;
                    }
                }
            }
```

**`// I am saving the following values in the session`**

```
  SessionWrapper.currentRequest.UserName = model.UserName;
    SessionWrapper.currentRequest.Role = aRole;
    SessionWrapper.currentRequest.UserId = userId;
```

**`The sessionState mode is SQLServer, and I can see data added to the both ASPSTATE tables. here is how I set up the session state in the config file`**

```
<sessionState mode="SQLServer" allowCustomSqlDatabase="true" timeout="60"
```

`cookieless="false" sqlConnectionString="Data Source=(****);Initial Catalog=data1;User` `ID=****;Password=****;Integrated Security=True" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not have a Session_start and Session_end method in my global.asax file. I added one, and the issue went away.